# How to combine arrays from a multidimensional array and count values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner at php and was searching for a solution all day long without success.

I have the following array:

```
$data = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [my_id] => 1
        [my_post_id] => 123
        [my_status] => 1
        [my_rating] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [my_id] => 2
        [my_post_id] => 123
        [my_status] => 1
        [my_rating] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [my_id] => 3
        [my_post_id] => 123
        [my_status] => 1
        [my_rating] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [my_id] => 4
        [my_post_id] => 456
        [my_status] => 1
        [my_rating] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [my_id] => 5
        [my_post_id] => 456
        [my_status] => 1
        [my_rating] => 3
    )
)
```

and would like to merge the arrays with the same 'my_post_id' and count the values for 'my_status' and 'my_rating' which have the same 'my_post_id'.

At the end, I would like to have the following array:

```
 $data = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [my_post_id] => 123
        [my_status] => 3
        [my_rating] => 14
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [my_post_id] => 456
        [my_status] => 2
        [my_rating] => 8
    )
)
```

I could get arrays with unique 'my_post_id' with the following code but I couldn't find out how to count the other values.

```
$out = array();
    foreach( $data as $row ) {
        $out[$row['my_post_id']] = $row;
    }
    $array = array_values( $out );
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Daniel

Comment: I'm sure you could do something with `if (isset($out[$row['my_post_id']])) { ... }`

Comment: Still don't understand how your `merge`  works...

Comment: take a look at MiDo and my posts below.  Both show you methods to increment(sum) the values.  the only real difference is his pushes the post_id up as the key field, whereas mine increments a non-related like you asked for.  I think if you reconsider your requirement, his makes more sense for your end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the array you are looking for:

```
$out = array();
foreach( $data as $row ) {
    if (!isset($out[$row['my_post_id']])) {
        $out[$row['my_post_id']] = Array( "my_id"=>$row['my_id'],
                                          "my_status" => $row["my_status"],
                                          "my_rating" => $row["my_rating"]);
    }
    else {
        $out[$row['my_post_id']]["my_status"] += $row["my_status"];
        $out[$row['my_post_id']]["my_rating"] += $row["my_rating"];
    }

}
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 1
            [my_status] => 3
            [my_rating] => 14
        )

    [456] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 4
            [my_status] => 2
            [my_rating] => 8
        )

)
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast :-) Thanks a lot for your help. It's much appreciated and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try the following - untested code

```
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    if(!array_search($val['my_post_id'],$newArray)){
        $newArray[]=array('my_post_id' => $val['my_post_id'], 
                          'my_status' => $val['my_status'],
                          'my_rating' => $val['my_rating']);
    }else{
        $myIndex=array_search($val['my_post_id'],$newArray);
        $newArray[$myIndex]['my_status']+=$val['my_status'];
        $newArray[$myIndex]['my_rating']+=$val['my_rating'];
    }
}
```